# Tensorflow - Total Variation Loss - reduce_sum vs reduce_mean?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

Why does the [Total Variation Loss in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/total_variation) suggest to use `reduce_sum` instead of `reduce_mean` as a loss function?

> This can be used as a loss-function during optimization so as to
>   suppress   noise in images. If you have a batch of images, then you
>   should calculate   the scalar loss-value as the sum:
>   `loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.image.total_variation(images))`

Comment: If you use `tf.reduce_mean` you loss value will be independent of `batch_size` which is desireable effect as I understand, but maybe using `tf.reduce_mean` will produce loss value that is too low, which can be undesireable effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I contacted the author and it seems there wasn't any important reason behind it at all. He mentioned that maybe `reduce_sum` worked better for his test case than `reduce_mean` but encouraged me to test both cases and choose the one which gives me the best results.